# get_the_title and get_permalink outside of the Loop

Tags: widgets, loop, get-the-title

I'm trying to list the parent to a page in the sidebar.  I can get the parent-page ID.  I can get it to print with a print_r function, but no matter what I try I can't get get_permalink and get_the_title to display.

```
  <?php
    global $wp_query;

  if(!$wp_query->post->post_parent){  //no parent
      $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&depth=1&child_of=".$wp_query->post->ID."&echo=0");   // will display the subpages of this top level page
  }else{    // diplays only the subpages of parent level

      if($wp_query->post->ancestors){
          $ancestors = end($wp_query->post->ancestors);
          $ancestorsID = get_post_ancestors($wp_query->post->ID); 
          $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$ancestors."&echo=0");}
  }

  if ($children) { 
      echo '<ul>';

      if($wp_query->post->ancestors){
      echo '<li>'; print_r($ancestorsID[0]); get_permalink($ancestorsID[0]); get_the_title($ancestorsID[0]); echo '</li>'; }

      else {echo '<li><a href="';the_permalink(); echo '" title="Permalink to ';the_title(); echo '" rel="bookmark">'; the_title(); echo '</a></li>';}
      echo $children;
      echo '</ul>';
  } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `echo` right before functions.

```
echo get_permalink($ancestorsID[0]); echo get_the_title($ancestorsID[0]);
```